# Timex Sinclair 1500 and screen "jail bars"

Tags: zx-spectrum, video, hardware-mods, sinclair

I have tried to eliminate "jail bars" on the screen after UHF mod to video out (based on that: http://zx81stuff.org.uk/zx81/ts1500_video.html) by adding 460uf 16V capacitor between +5V and GND but it didn't do anything to reduce them.

Any thought on that?

This is how it looks on the screen: 
[image]

Comment: You might want to try asking at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Aybe Maybe not - The TS1500/ZX81 screen output is a mix of (very) tricky Z80 software and some (relatively) simple electronics. Even if I doubt someone would be able to actually get rid of the bars, the biggest chances of solving that would be with ZX81 experts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pokemon on the German ZX Forum has designed a number of video improvement circuits (ZX81CPP, ZX81SCP) that allow connection of a composite video monitor and produce a crystal clear picture once properly adjusted.

https://www.sinclairzxworld.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=841&sid=9e23e93b43bfcc0bb782a80803430e70

The circuit basically completely re-creates the video signal from the ULA output.

Newer versions have an ATTiny(I think) on board that keeps the sync alive during fast mode which is a relief on modern LCD screens as they tend to get upset otherwise.

Every once in a while he offers PCBs and completely built circuits (which, BTW, nicely fit into the modulator case if cleaned up a bit).